# Ajax phonegap image post

Tags: ajax, json, image, cordova

Below is the piece of code i have used:

```
 JSON.stringify({
                request:
                    {

                        "Ticket": "String content",
                        "Picture": {
                           "Name": "blabla",
                            "ImgData": "blabla",

                        },
                    }
            });
```

i have picture , i captured with phonegap and i wanna post it with json. is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Upload/Post image using phonegap

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
   var imagefile = imageURI;        
   var ft = new FileTransfer();                     
   var options = new FileUploadOptions();                      
   options.fileKey="vImage1";                      
   options.fileName=imagefile.substr(imagefile.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
   options.mimeType="image/jpeg";  
   var params = new Object();
   params.value1 = "test";
   params.value2 = "param";                       
   options.params = params;
   options.chunkedMode = false;                       
   ft.upload(imagefile, your_service_url, win, fail, options);   
 }

 function win(r) {
   console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
   console.log("Response = " + r.response);
   //alert($.parseJSON(r.response))    
 }

function fail(error) {
   console.log("Response = " +  error.code);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to upload it inside json data you'll need to send the image encoded in base64, for that use the `destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` when you take the picture